# How to add a number to every item in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list similar to this:

```
list1=['a','b','c']
```

I want the new edited list to display the following:

```
list2=['1a','2b','3c']
```

I tried many codes but only managed to display the number after the text and not before.

Comment: `[str(i+1) + e for i, e in enumerate(list1)]`

Comment: Or `[str(i) + e for i, e in enumerate(list1, start=1)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple and understandable loop:

```
list2 = []
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    list2.append(str(i+1) + item)
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate

```
list2 = [f"{a+1}{i}" for a,i in enumerate(list1)]
```

Or here is another solution that uses `index()` instead

```
list2 = [f"{list1.index(i)+1}{i}" for i in list1]
```